# D3 Pie chart initial render issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Looking at implementing a d3 pie chart, and the initial draw of the pie chart is not rendering properly. Once I call a redraw (randomize top left) however, it falls into place as expected, and then future ones transition as expected.

Am I doing something wrong here when initializing the chart for the first time?

https://codepen.io/MattN96/pen/xxdVjRN

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> 

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

path.slice{
    stroke-width:2px;
}

polyline{
    opacity: .3;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<button class="randomize">randomize</button>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.2/d3.min.js" data-semver="5.9.2" data-require="d3@*"></script>
<script>
  
 var arc, outerArc, width, height, radius;
  
 var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });
  
  var key = function(d){ return d.data.label; };

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet"])
    .range(["#98abc5", "#6b486b", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);


function randomData (){
    var labels = ["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet"];
    return labels.map(function(label){
        return { label: label, value: Math.random() }
    });
}

initialRender(randomData());  
  
redraw(randomData());
 
d3.select(".randomize")
    .on("click", function(){
        redraw(randomData()); 
    });
 
 
function initialRender(data){
  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .append("g") 
  
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g") 
    .attr("class", "lines");

 
width = 960;
    height = 450;
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
 
var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });

arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.4);

outerArc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

}
function redraw(data) { 

  var pieData = pie(data);
  
  var svg = d3.select("body")
  
  
    var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
        .data(pieData, key); 

    text.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.data.label;
        });
    
    function midAngle(d){ 
        return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
    }

    text.transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return "translate("+ pos +")";
            };
        })
        .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
            };
        });

    text.exit()
        .remove();

    /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/

    var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
        .data(pieData, key);
    
    polyline.enter()
        .append("polyline");

    polyline.transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("points", function(d){
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
            };          
        }); 
    
    polyline.exit()
        .remove();
  
    /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
  
    var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
        .data(pieData, key);

    slice.enter()
        .insert("path")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.label); })
        .attr("class", "slice");
 
    slice       
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) { 
                return arc(interpolate(t));
            };
        })

    slice.exit()
        .remove();

    /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

};

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. Your problem is here:

```
text.transition().duration(1000)
```

Likewise for the polyline and slice transitions. On the first render there is no actual text on the dom selected in the variable `text`. You subsequently append the text, but appending does not alter your original selection variable.  You need to reselect each after the enter, append.  Selecting the enter append didn't work later because future enter append selections would be empty (you never add any new slices, etc)

```
 var arc, outerArc, width, height, radius;
  
 var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });
  
  var key = function(d){ return d.data.label; };

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet"])
    .range(["#98abc5", "#6b486b", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);


function randomData (){
    var labels = ["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet"];
    return labels.map(function(label){
        return { label: label, value: Math.random() }
    });
}

initialRender(randomData());  
  
redraw(randomData());
 
d3.select(".randomize")
    .on("click", function(){
        redraw(randomData()); 
    });
 
 
function initialRender(data){
  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .append("g") 
  
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g") 
    .attr("class", "lines");

 
width = 960;
    height = 450;
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
 
var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });

arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.4);

outerArc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

}
function redraw(data) { 

  var pieData = pie(data);
  
  var svg = d3.select("body")
  
  
    var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
        .data(pieData, key); 

    text.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.data.label;
        });
    
  var textPath= svg.selectAll('text')
  
    function midAngle(d){ 
        return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
    }

    textPath.transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return "translate("+ pos +")";
            };
        })
        .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
            };
        });

    text.exit()
        .remove();

    /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/

    var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
        .data(pieData, key);
    
    polyline.enter()
        .append("polyline");
  
  var polyPath= svg.selectAll('polyline')
  
    polyPath.transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("points", function(d){
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
            };          
        }); 
    
    polyPath.exit()
        .remove();
  
    /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
  
    var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
        .data(pieData, key);

    slice.enter()
        .insert("path")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.label); })
        .attr("class", "slice");
  
  
  var slicePath = svg.selectAll('.slice')
  
 
    slicePath       
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) { 
                return arc(interpolate(t));
            };
        })

    slice.exit()
        .remove();
```

Comment: I made the recommended changes to the code, and now it rendering initially, but does not redraw? See codepen here - https://codepen.io/MattN96/pen/xxdVjRN

Comment: Silly mistake by me, please try the js in the new solution posted.

Comment: Right you are! Can be confusing when getting used to d3

Comment: The latest versions have a method that simplifies the enter, update, remove system.